# RLS issues in Supabase arise when attempting to filter products based on the `company_id` stored in `auth.user_metadata`

Tags: postgresql, supabase, supabase-database, supabase-js

I want to show a list of products to the right employees. Based on the structure below:

- **Tina** works at **Company A (10)**, so I want them to see **Apple**
- **Sam** works at **Company B (11)**, so they will see **Banana**.

Here are my tables:

[image]
I have a function that is triggered to set `auth.usermeta` & it works as it should:

```
const { data:authData, error: authErr } = await supabase.auth.updateUser({
            data: {
                company_id, // company_id is a string I got from the session
                role: 'manager'
            }
        });
```

Now on the product table on Supabase, I set this RLS on SELECT:

```
auth.jwt() -> 'user_metadata' ->> 'company_id' = (company_id)::text
```

Everything seems to be going OK (no error), however - I see the wrong products (and sometimes even no product) on user's dashboard. I have tested different SQL code including converting `user_metadata` `company_id` to `bigint`:

```
((((auth.jwt() -> 'user_metadata'::text) ->> 'company_id'::text))::bigint = company_id)
```

But same result, products just don't seem to show correctly :(

I finally gave up tackle this from the FE and it works as expected:

```
const { data, error: err } = await supabase
    .from('product')
    .select()
    .eq('company_id', session?.user.user_metadata.company_id);
```

I prefer to solve this using RLS instead of always passing `session?.user.user_metadata.company_id`. Why don't the products show correctly when I used the SQL expression?

*My project uses Supabase(^2.39.1) and Sveltekit(^2.0.0)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution!

I used `refreshSession` after `updateUser` and then `auth.jwt() -> 'user_metadata' ->> 'company_id' = (company_id)::text` on RLS SQL check :)